# How? I show a message, while the task is running

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following code.

A method compress (), where I do the task of compressing an entire directory, I call this method from my button, with a QtConcurrent, as you can see. so far so good.

My question is, how can I display a message while compressing the folder is running.

I am using QuaZIP, for the compression process.

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class Widget; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class Widget : public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
  ~Widget();
 
private slots:
  void on_pushButton_5_clicked();

private:
  Ui::Widget *ui;
  void compress();
public:
 
};
#endif // WIDGET_H

#include "widget.h"
#include "ui_widget.h"
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QDebug>
#include <JlCompress.h>
#include <QtConcurrent/QtConcurrent>
#include <QFuture>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
  : QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
  ui->setupUi(this); 
}
Widget::~Widget()
{
  delete ui;
}
void Widget::on_pushButton_5_clicked()
{
  QGuiApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::WaitCursor);
  QFuture<void> future=QtConcurrent::run(this,&Widget::compress);
  future.waitForFinished();
  QGuiApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();
  QMessageBox::information(this,qApp->applicationName(),"The folder was compressed successfully.");
}
void Widget::compress()
{
  if(!JlCompress::compressDir("C:/Users/Mypc/Desktop/iconos.zip", "D:/images/iconos")){
    QMessageBox::warning(this,qApp->applicationName(),"Error compressing folder.");
    return;
  }
}
```

I did this, but now when the backup finishes, the entire application closes.

```
    void Widget::on_pushButton_5_clicked()
    {
      
      QMessageBox box;
  //  box->setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog | Qt::SplashScreen);
  box.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::NoButton);
  box.setText("Realizando una tarea!");
  box.setWindowTitle(qApp->applicationName());
  box.setIcon(QMessageBox::Information);
  box.setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);

  QFutureWatcher<void> watcher;

  QFuture<void> future=QtConcurrent::run(this,&Widget::compress);
  watcher.setFuture(future);

  QGuiApplication::setOverrideCursor(Qt::WaitCursor);

  QObject::connect(&watcher,&QFutureWatcher<void>::finished,[&](){

    box.close();
    box.deleteLater();
    QGuiApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();
  });
  box.exec();
      QMessageBox::information(this,qApp->applicationName(), "The folder was compressed successfully.");
    
    }
```

Also try a ProgressDialog and QFutureWatcher as follows, but it doesn't compile, I get this error.

[image]

```
void Widget::on_pushButton_5_clicked()
{

  QStringList files;
  QDir dir("D:/images/iconos/uigenericicon");
  files=dir.entryList(QStringList() << "*.jpg" << "*.JPG"<<"*.PNG",QDir::Files);
  
  qInfo()<<files;

  QProgressDialog pDialog;
  pDialog.setLabelText("Porecessing!!");

  QFutureWatcher<void> watcher;

  QObject::connect(&pDialog,SIGNAL(canceled()),&watcher,SLOT(cancel()));
  QObject::connect(&watcher,SIGNAL(finished()),&pDialog,SLOT(reset()));
  QObject::connect(&watcher,SIGNAL(progressRangeChanged(int,int)),&pDialog,SLOT(setRange(int,int)));
  QObject::connect(&watcher,SIGNAL(progressValueChanged(int)),&pDialog,SLOT(setValue(int)));

  watcher.setFuture(QtConcurrent::map(files,&Widget::compress));
  pDialog.exec();
  if(watcher.isCanceled()){
    QMessageBox::information(this,qApp->applicationName(),"You canceled.");
  }else{
    QMessageBox::information(this,qApp->applicationName(),"All done.");
  }
}

void Widget::compress(QStringList &files)
{

  if(!JlCompress::compressFiles("C:/Users/Lincoln/Desktop/iconos.zip",files)){
    QMessageBox::warning(this,qApp->applicationName(),"Error al comprimir la carpeta.");
    return;
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a non-blocking QMessageBox?

Comment: Do the actual compression in a worker thread, leaving your UI thread unblocked to display the message, which you can close once the thread is finished.

Comment: You need to get rid of `future.waitForFinished();` that will prevent the GUI up from updating as long as the concurrent job is running. Remember that the GUI will not update until it exits your function and returns to the event loop. Your QMessageBox may also be problematic in that you should display that from the GUI thread and not the worker.

Comment: If you want to use QtConcurrent you may need: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuturewatcher.html](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfuturewatcher.html)

Comment: The `if(watcher.isCanceled()){` part should be in the reset() function.

Comment: I already did that, and the same problem keeps getting.